# How to return index for each level of a multiindex corresponding to the maximum value of a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The groups of my data frame are defined by two indexed columns (`cat1` and `cat2`). For a third, non-indexed variable, `var`, I want to find the index `cat2`, for max value of `var` for each value of `cat1`.
When I use `idxmax()`, I get the overall index value of both `cat1` and `cat2` corresponding to max value of `var` which is `(B,dog)`. I want this value for each level of `cat1`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat1': ['A'] * 4 + ['B'] * 4 + ['C'] * 4,
    'cat2': ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bear'] * 3,
    'var': [23, 33, 45, 66, 77, 88, 44, 55, 33, 22, 11, 44],
}).set_index(['cat1', 'cat2'])

            var
cat1 cat2      
A    cat     23
     dog     33
     mouse   45
     bear    66
B    cat     77
     dog     88
     mouse   44
     bear    55
C    cat     33
     dog     22
     mouse   11
     bear    44
```

This is the result produced:

[image: current result]

Desired results:

[image: result desired]

I don't care about the format.

Comment: kindly provide reproducible data, not pics. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df.groupby('cat1').idxmax()  # or df.groupby(level=0).idxmax()

#             var
# cat1           
# A     (A, bear)
# B      (B, dog)
# C     (C, bear)
```

- Your current code uses [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), which returns the index of the **global** max.
- However you just want the index of **each group's** max, so use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html).

<sub>(In the future, please provide sample dataframes as copy-pastable code rather than as images, as sammywemmy said.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite ways to create the output of this code. I demonstrated below 3 ways:

```
MaxEachcat1 = df[df['var'] == df.groupby(level=[0])['var'].transform(max)]

print(MaxEachcat1)
print(MaxEachcat1.index)
print(MaxEachcat1.index[0])
```

output:

```
# way 1
            var
cat1 cat2
A    bear   66
B    dog    88
C    bear   44

# way 2
MultiIndex([('A', 'bear'),
            ('B',  'dog'),
            ('C', 'bear')],
           names=['cat1', 'cat2'])

# way 3
('A', 'bear')
```